# Why can't I shoot continously with my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: continuous-drive

What is the reason I can not shoot continuous shots on my nikon d90 for action shots? It only allows me to shoot one frame. I am using a Tamron 200-500 lens.

Comment: Describing what mode you are in on the main mode dial would be helpful. What AutoFocus mode are you in(or manual mode)? Are you in a continuous mode as it notes on page 65 of your manual? Finally, have you looked at page 54 of your manual? What about that(if anything) does not make sense? Does this happen with other lenses?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your drive mode is wrong.  If you are in Nikon's version of easy automatic focus, it likely locks down settings like drive mode so that they aren't even an option.  Even if you are in the creative auto mode, you still need to select continuous drive to be able to shoot continuously.  If you have single shot drive selected, then you will only be able to take one shot at a time.